# Cannot create files on Android with Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I have a Xamarin-Studio App for Android and I simply want to download files  and save them locally. But when I try to create a file in the `files` folder I get an exception:

```
File.Create("data/data/com.company.app/files/newFile.png");
```

gives me:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException
Access to the path 'data/data/com.company.app/files/newFile.png' is denied.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you using  Mac OS X?

Comment: How do you know "files" exists? Are you checking for this?

Comment: Yes I am on OS X. I have rooted my test device and have checked with Root Browser that `files` does exist. Also I am using a Dropbox framework that successfully creates files there. I am just not able to create files manually...

Comment: Shouldn't the path have a leading slash in front?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally realized that `File.create()` was not the problem. I had code like this:

```
string tmpFilePath = FilesDir.AbsolutePath.stringByAppendingPath (f.Path);
Java.IO.File tmpFile = new Java.IO.File( tmpFilePath);
tmpFile.Mkdirs ();
```

Yet, `Mkdirs()` does not only create all intermediate directories – as I had assumed – but also creates a directory at the file path itself. So the file could not be created because there already was a directory with the same name.
The correct way is:

```
string tmpFile = FilesDir.AbsolutePath.stringByAppendingPath (f.Path);
Java.IO.File tmpParentFolder = new Java.IO.File(tmpFile).getParentFile();
tmpParentFolder.Mkdirs ();
```

In my defense, an `FileExistsAndIsDirectory` exception would have been much more helpful than the `UnauthorizedAccessException`

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/

Answer (score 16):

You should use Environment or IsolatedStorage. For example:

```
var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
var filename = Path.Combine(path, "newFile.png");
```

Answer (score 7):

I am coding Xamarin with VS2013. I had the access denied error for a directory created with the application I am writing.  My application creates a directory called `/storage/emulated/0/POIApp` by concatenating via:

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path, "POIApp");
```

I found that I had to use VS2013 to edit the "properties" of my application (POIApp), i.e., right-click the project icon in the solution explorer; choose properties from the pop-up menu.  A new tab appears in the main VS2013 window. On the left there are a few choices, e.g., Application, Android Manifest, Android Options, Build, etc.  Choose "Android Manifest".  At the bottom of the main panel is a section "required permissions".  My problem was solved when I checked "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" and "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE".

Answer (score 3):

Add the following permission to Android.Manifest file

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Answer (score 1):

Using Mono, I think must be the same as in Xamarin Studio.

```
var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
File.Create(path + "newFile.png");
```

Comment: Doesn't that give me the file path to the SD-Card? I need to write the the internal storage within the Apps bundle.

Comment: Try `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);`

Comment: System.Environment Does not contain the method GetFolderPath