# Android - Xamarin UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/storage/sdcard0/ denied

Tags: c#, io, xamarin.android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am trying to access one file from the device memory. below was the code

```
string directory = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath);
string Mp3 = Path.Combine(directory, "root.txt");
Toast.MakeText(Activity , "directory: " + directory, ToastLength.Long).Show();
if (File.Exists(Mp3))
{
    string applicationFolderPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "STRACK");
    File.Copy(Mp3, applicationFolderPath+ "/root.txt");
}
else
{
    Toast.MakeText(Activity, "directory: " + directory, ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

AndroidManifest file also changes as

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

But I am getting error `UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/storage/sdcard0/ denied`

My Android version is Jelly bean

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707138/cannot-create-files-on-android-with-xamarin

Answer (score 0):

Use 
    Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path
instead of
    Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath
that fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue finally

line  `android:maxSdkVersion="18"` making the issue I have removed it and got worked