# Download and open picture from url/http [Android Xamarin App]

Tags: image, xamarin.android, download, save

**Hello, would any of you send a working code to download a photo from a given http address on android Xamarin c #?**
First, I need to create a new folder for my application files.
My goal is to download the file from the internet to my Android folder (saving this file with its original name is best).
The next step is to display the image from that folder in "ImageView". It is also important that there are permissions in android and I do not fully understand it.
Could any of you send it to me or help me understand it and explain the topic?

*Actually i have this code:

```
string address = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3V3w.png";
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
     webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += WebClient_DownloadFileCompleted;
     webClient.DownloadFile(address, Path.Combine(pathDire, "MyNewImage1.png"));
     //System.Net.WebException: 'An exception occurred during a WebClient request.'
}
```

Comment: About download image from url and display in imageview, you can look [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23860511/load-image-from-url-to-imageview-c-sharp), if you want to create new folder for your app, please take a look:[create files on Android with Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707138/cannot-create-files-on-android-with-xamarin), but you need to add permission about `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, please take a look:[Permissions In Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading image from url  and display in imageview.

```
 private void Btn1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var imageBitmap = GetImageBitmapFromUrl("http://xamarin.com/resources/design/home/devices.png");
        imagen.SetImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }

    private Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
    {
        Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
            if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
            {

                SavePicture("ImageName.jpg", imageBytes, "imagesFolder");
                imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            }
        }

        return imageBitmap;
    }
```

download image and save it in local storage.

```
 private void SavePicture(string name, byte[] data, string location = "temp")
    {
        
        var documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        documentsPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsPath, "Orders", location);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(documentsPath);

        string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsPath, name);      
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {             
            int length = data.Length;
            fs.Write(data, 0, length);
        }
    }
```

you need to add permission `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in `AndroidMainfeast.xml`, then you also need to Runtime Permission Checks in Android 6.0.

```
  private void checkpermission()
    {
        if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) == (int)Permission.Granted)
        {
            // We have permission, go ahead and use the writeexternalstorage.
        }
        else
        {
            // writeexternalstorage permission is not granted. If necessary display rationale & request.
        }
        if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage) == (int)Permission.Granted)
        {
            // We have permission, go ahead and use the ReadExternalStorage.
        }
        else
        {
            // ReadExternalStorage permission is not granted. If necessary display rationale & request.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much!